# How can I know who calls the method in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Does Xcode have a way to show the caller function of a method? I want to know all of the calling functions of a method in a class.  A solution would be to find the method in the project, but sometimes different classes have methods with the same name - That could find us a method we're not looking for..

Many other IDEs have this capability, such as Visual C++ 2003/2005/2008,Eclipse ...

Can you do this in XCode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xcode 4.4 intrudced this functionality:
[New Features in Xcode 4.4](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_4.html) (Scroll down to 'Find and Search Additions')

1. Move your cursor on top of the function you are interested in
2. Open the Assistant editor(**⌃** +**⌘**+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
3. On the top of the assistant editor, Select 'Callers'
   [image: Assistant editor - Callers]
4. You will see a list of all the function that's calling your function
   [image: Assistant editor - dropdown]

Not the as effective as other IDEs, but does the job.

Comment: faster way to open the above pop-up menu is to just highlight the method where you want to know the callers and hit Ctrl+1; no need to actually open the assistant editor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Set a breakpoint inside your method, then when it breaks, there are two spots to see a stack. First is in Xcode's "console" area (usually the bottom middle), there is a top-bar which may not immediately appear to be navigable, but it is a select-style UI control which has the entire stack in it. Selecting a different level shows you that scope's variables, etc.  *and* pops your editor to that exact file (where you can mouse-over variables to see their in-memory real-time values). Second is in the left-hand area (where you normally browse files). There is another tab there (besides the file browser) for exactly this purpose. There is a slider at the bottom which controls how many "steps" in the stack you see; clicking on one has a similar affect.

[image: Xcode showing full stack access on breakpoint]

For simple refactoring such as method re-naming, you can use the contextual-menu when you right-click a selected method-name, and Xcode will replace all identical selectors in your project. However, this does not address what you mentioned about different classes having methods with the same signature. It does, however, give you a very nice interface for reviewing the changes in-context and easily accepting or rejecting them one at a time.

It might be noted, however, that changing method signatures often may be a sign of poor design, and particularly if you have to do it with methods which have the same signature on different classes (which are not "siblings" and therefore should both get the rename)

Comment: I'm sorry. Maybe I didn't express my meaning clearly. I did't want to know who call the method when the app running . I want to know every one who may call the method. For the purpose that I'll know who was affect when I change the method. Or I can controll all the entrance of this methord.